# Making dynamic Banner Ad in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uiscrollview, uiimageview, scroll, smartbanner

I am new in iOS 7. I am trying to implement a dynamic Banner Ad in my app, where the images will be located to the remote server, I want to parse the images and display them in the banner. It will be great honor for me if anyone guide me to do this with algorithms or helpful code or tutorial.